# Drawing a D3.js cluster with the smallest possible height

Tags: d3.js, hierarchy, dendrogram

Is there a way to dynamically set the height of a D3.js cluster so that it will have the smallest height possible (i.e. the smallest height before the edges of the dendrogram begin to get cut off or nodes start overlapping)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/d3-js/element%2420dynamic%2420height/d3-js/7Js0dGrnyek/MfGJAdiPlQwJ) on the D3.js Google Group finally answered the question for me. I also changed my cluster to a tree. Hope this helps someone else with the same problem!